# Selenium Webdriver + jQuery локаторы

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Доброго времени суток. Мо;но ли как-то в Selenium Webdriver реализовать метод поиска по jquery локаторам? Может быть есть подключаемая библиотека, или можно каким-то образом переопределить метод findElements(By. ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно, но не рекомендуется. Если вы знаете jQuery, то знаете как работают CSS селекторы. Зачем тогда нужен jQuery?

[Ответ на Stackoverflow (en)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555280/selenium-webdriver-jquery#17784707)

Comment: Поставлена задача в проект на Elenium добавить возможность работы с jQUery. Вот, узнаю как это все реализовать. О jQuery, если честно, знаю очень мало. Но, судя по Вашему ответу, это тот же css?

Comment: Посмотрите, что пишут люди по ссылке - мне кажется, там хороший ответ по Java. Я работаю с NodeJS. Второй способ -
перенести всю работу с jQuery внутри Javascript: если на странице уже есть jQuery, то можно внутри executeScript() использовать его. А в селениум передавать уже результат executeScript() и делать assert с эталонным значением.